# How to determine the underlying MapReduce jobs in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce

Given a Spark application, how to determine how the application is mapped into its underlying MapReduce jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spark application itself doesn't know anything about the underlying execution framework. That is part of the abstraction which allows to run in the different modes (local, mesos, standalone, yarn.client and yarn-cluster).

You will however see the yarn application id after submitting your application with spark-submit, it's usually something like this:

application_1453729472522_0110

You can also use the yarn command to list currently running applications like this:

yarn application -list

that will print all applications running in the cluster, Spark applications have the appliccationType SPARK.

Answer (score 1):

I would say each stage is a *MapReduce* job. I can not give you a reference for this, but from my experience, looking at the stage construction you can see what was cast as a *Map* phase (chained `map`s, `filter`s, `flatMap`s) and what was cast as a *Reduce* phase (`groupBy`,`collect`,`join`,etc) and grouped into one stage. You can also deduce *Map* only or *Reduce* only *Mapreduce* jobs.

It also helps to output the DAG as you see again the same chaning.

You can access the Stages in the Spark UI while your spark job is running.

**Disclaimer** This is deduced from experience and deduction reasoning.

Comment: In fact it isn't - a spark job will block a vcpu on a given node (this is controlled using task an executor paramaters), any closure will run on any of these assigned vcpus within the DAG. Map Reduce has very strict orders of execution, which involves flushing results to disk at the end, with a map and then a reduce phase. This strict order of execution doesn't apply to Spark at all.

Comment: You are right, but I was not refering to Hadoop, just MapReduce model.